# Flutter debugger crashes when image picker is cancelled

Tags: dart, flutter

When I cancel image gallery picker my flutter debugger suddenly crashes with such log. This is not possible to continue debugging.
[image]

Is it possible to skip this? Or this is just a temporary bug?

```
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'className' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: className
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
#1      serializeProcedure (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/utils.dart:99:29)
#2      FrontendCompiler.compileExpression (package:vm/frontend_server.dart:482:16)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _FlutterFrontendCompiler.compileExpression (package:frontend_server/server.dart:62:22)
#4      listenAndCompile.<anonymous closure> (package:vm/frontend_server.dart:797:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
#6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
#8      _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:68:11)
#9      _EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:15:11)
#10     _StringAdapterSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:268:11)
#11     _LineSplitterSink._addLines (dart:convert/line_splitter.dart:154:13)
#12     _LineSplitterSink.addSlice (dart:convert/line_splitter.dart:129:5)
#13     StringConversionSinkMixin.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:189:5)
#14     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:120:24)
#15     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
#16     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#17     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
#18     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:68:11)
#19     _EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:15:11)
#20     _StringAdapterSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:268:11)
#21     _StringAdapterSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:273:7)
#22     _Utf8ConversionSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:348:20)
#23     _Utf8ConversionSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:341:5)
#24     _ConverterStreamEventSink.add (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:86:18)
#25     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:120:24)
#26     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
#27     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#28     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
#29     _SyncStreamController._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:763:19)
#30     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:639:7)
#31     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:585:5)
#32     _Socket._onData (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:1721:41)
#33     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
#34     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#35     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
#36     _SyncStreamController._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:763:19)
#37     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:639:7)
#38     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:585:5)
#39     new _RawSocket.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:1283:33)
#40     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:826:14)
#41     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#42     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#43     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#44     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
Unhandled exception:
SocketException: Write failed (OS Error: Broken pipe, errno = 32), port = 0
#0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1112:29)
#1      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#2      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#3      _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

This is the code I use

```
var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are canceling the picker so it returns `null` as expected. You should handle it.

You have also the [file_picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/file_picker) plugin that includes image picker and also has the options to pick other file formats, if you want.

Comment: Actually I don’t see it directly related to the image picker plugin in the logs. Might be due to something that you’re doing within your app after picking an image. Could you update your question with the code block where you’re calling the picker?

Comment: Look at the last string of the question

Comment: Yes but that’s not enough. What are you doing with the `image` once picker returns?

Comment: It really doesn't matter because the debugger crashes namely at this line. No more executions

Comment: Furthermore , the application works as expected. But I can't debug